# Draw svg using fonts on canvas without using defs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fonts

I need to draw a svg which use external resources css in a canvas but cannot (or should not) include the style in defs since the svg will be use a lot of times in the canvas.

When I convert the SVGElement to a HTMLImageElement I loss the reference to the style.

Is it possible to obtain the render of a SVGElement in the browser and then draw it in a canvas ?
If not is there an other method to resolve my issue ?

Here is the case that I am trying to resolve:

```js
var svgToParse = '\
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30">\
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="14" fill="red" />\
  <text class="testCss" x="50%" y="65%" text-anchor="middle">&#xf040;</text>\
</svg>\
';
var domParser = new DOMParser();
var svgDoc = domParser.parseFromString(svgToParse, "image/svg+xml");

var container = document.getElementById('test_container_id');

var svg1 = svgDoc.documentElement.cloneNode(true);

// Result to obtain in canvas
container.appendChild(
 svg1
);

// Canvas
var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg2 = new Blob([svgToParse], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg2);

img.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('canvas_id')
 .getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.testCss {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="test_container_id">
  <h3>
    Needed in canvas:
  </h3>
</div>

<h3>
Canvas:
</h3>
<canvas id="canvas_id" width="100" height="100">
  
</canvas>
```

Comment: nope you can't load external resources from an img element which must be used to display an svg on the canvas. So you must include the external resources inside your svg markup.

Comment: Well actually you could of course use canvas API methods to reproduce your svg instead of using drawImage. A library like canvg might help.

Comment: PPs: Since the font you need to display is font-awesome, and that there is an svg version of this font file, you could also make something smart enough to parse the original font file, and only include the glyphs required. Also, your statement *"since the svg will be use a lot of times in the canvas."* seems a bit biased, you'll load only once the svg into an `<img>` tag, then the browser doesn't need to load it each time you use `drawImage`.

Comment: @Kaiido The svg will not be loaded once since in the real scenarios it will not be the same that are put on canvas but generated ones, the only common part of the svgs is the use of the font. But yes I could include the glyphs required in the svg that could work, I will try that.